# Angular leaflet maps show grey color with tile layer

Tags: angularjs, leaflet, angular-leaflet-directive

I'm using `angular-leaflet-directive` to render leaflet maps on my web-app, also I'm getting tiles from [Carto](http://carto.com) service. The problem is that when I add the tile layer, the tiles apeear as expected but the whole map fills with grey color. Any ideas what could cause such a behavior?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27610078/angular-leaflet-directive-issue-where-the-map-is-technically-rendering-but-no or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35202437/leaflet-map-inside-jqwidget-resulting-in-grey-tiles or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34931444/map-based-on-leaflet-and-angularjs-not-loaded-correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

had same problem 
make sure you doesn't override leaflet style

In my case the following style caused the problem

```
img{
max-width:100%;
max-height:100%;
}
```